# I don't really understand this calc question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What do you even do here? Take the other two variable to RHS?

[image]

Comment: Take logs and differentiate with respect to $x$ treating $y$ as constant.

Comment: Nope, I haven't.

Comment: And note that we use $\dfrac{\partial} {\partial x} $ symbol here instead of $\dfrac{d} {dx} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have $$z^z = cx^{-x}y^{-y}$$, then $z\log z = \log c-x\log x - y\log y$.
So $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\log z + \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\log x - 1.$$

Then, $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{1+\log x}{1+\log z}$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Start by considering,

$$z^z = \dfrac{c}{x^xy^y}$$

Next, apply logarithm laws to obtain,

$$z\log (z) = \log (c) - x\log (x) + y\log (y)$$

Hopefully, from here you can apply ideas of partial differentiation to obtain your answer (the product rule will come in handy).